# Lifting flat modules over ring quotients

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, flatness, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $I$ its ideal, and $\bar{R}=R/I$. For which flat $\bar{R}$-modules $\bar{F}$ is there a flat $R$-module $F$ such that $F \otimes_R R/I \simeq \bar{F}$?

By Lazard's Theorem, each flat module is a direct limit of free modules of finite rank. If the underlying direct system is $\omega$, we can just lift the maps of the direct system (as they are just matrices), and that does the trick. This gives an affirmative answer for all countably presented flat $\bar{R}$-modules.

For general directed systems however, I see no reason for this to work. Am I wrong? Do you know about a counterexample, reference...? Thanks!

Comment: There are projective modules (=finitely generated flat modules) over $\overline{R}$ which do not lift to projective modules over $R$, so I am skeptical of your argument using Lazard's theorem.

Comment: @Mohan An example of a projective that doesn’t lift to a projective is $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $I=6\mathbb{Z}$, $P=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. But applying Fred.Fred’s construction, $P$ *does* lift to a flat $\mathbb{Z}$-module, namely $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{3}]$. Is this example enough to defuse your skepticism?

Comment: Where does the argument using Lazard's Theorem break down for a general directed system?

Comment: @MahdiMajidi-Zolbanin If the directed system is not well-ordered, lifting the maps between the finitely generated free $\bar{R}$-modules of the system arbitrarily may not yield a directed system of $R$-modules, or at least, I do not see a way how to ensure that.